# What does the line integral of $\int\vec{s}\cdot d\vec{F}$ represent, where $s$ is the total displacement, and $dF$ is the force differential?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, integration

I recently started reading Feynman Lectures on Physics (Vol 1). I came across the formula for work done as,

> Work done is $\int\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s}$

My question is:

> What does $\int\vec{s}\cdot d\vec{F}$ represent?

Does it even make sense to calculate the product of total displacement and small amount of force?

or does $\int\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s}$ have the same meaning as $\int\vec{s}\cdot d\vec{F}$, they both represent the work done?

Comment: The force is in principle a function $F(x,\dot{x},t)$, so you can integrate it along paths. I don't understand what sort of mathematical object you think $S$ is so that you could integrate it.

Comment: Since $y=x^3\implies ydx=x^3dx,\,xdy=3x^3dx$, you can't just commute quantities either side of $d$.

Comment: and $\vec s$ is not a vector, but the tanget $\vec{ds}$ is.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/382726/2451